# Selecting column after filtering

Tags: excel, vba

this code is supposed to select all the values from the column 'processes' where a flag is set to Y but it's only selecting the first 4 cells

```
Dim processes As Variant
Worksheets("Processes").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Y"
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
processes = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processes").Range("B2:B" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Comment: @BigBen no change there

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing the issue then is reading the `.Value` of a range with multiple `Areas` will only get the values from the first area... see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51026754/vba-copy-multiple-ranges-into-array-no-looping) for example... or create a loop. Actually [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993915/get-values-from-union-of-non-contiguous-ranges-into-array-with-vba-with-a-simple) is even better.

Comment: @BigBen `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Processes").Range("B2:B" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select` does select the entire column

Comment: Yes... but since that range has more than one area (it is not all contiguous), `processes` will only contain the values from the first area.

Comment: If you want to put the values from a non-contiguous range into an array, you will need to first size the array to the total number of cells, then loop over the cells and fill the array.